# Cannot find symbol error, don't understand why

Tags: java

I've been correcting mistakes within my code but I'm stuck on two different Cannot find symbol errors. One is a1 on a few lines, (example, line 55 in addressbookmain.java and Contact on a few lines, (example, line 47 in addressbookmain.java. If anyone could explain why i would appreciate it very much!

Code:

contacts.java

```
public class contacts {
private String name;
private String housenum;
private String streetname;
private String town;
private String postcode;
private String address;

public Contact(String inname, String inhousenum, String instreetname, String intown, String inpostcode, String inaddress) {
    this.name = inname;
    this.housenum = inhousenum;
    this.streetname = instreetname;
    this.town = intown;
    this.postcode = inpostcode;
    this.address = inaddress
}



public address getaddress() {
    return address
}

public String getname() {
    return name;
}

public String gethousenum() {
    return housenum;
}

public String getstreetname() {
    return streetname;
}

public String gettown() {
    return town;
}

public String getpostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

public String getaddress() {
    return name;
    return housenum;
    return streetname;
    return town;
    return postcode;
}
}
```

AddressBook.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddressBook {
public Contact[] contacts = new Contact[10];
private int count = 0;
private String fileName;

public AddressBook(String fileName) {
this.fileName = fileName;
}

public boolean add(Contact c) {
if(count > 9) {
    return false;
}
contacts[count] = c;
count++;
return true;
}

public boolean remove(String deleteContact) {
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if (contacts[i].getname() == deleteContact) {
        contacts[i] = null;
        contacts[i] = contacts[i-1];
    }
}
count--;
return true;
}

public Contact search(String searchContact){
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
    if (contacts[i].getname() == searchContact) {
        return contacts[i];
    }
return null;
}
}

public void output() {
System.out.println("Showing Contacts");
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    System.out.println(contacts[i].getname() + " " + contacts[i].gethousenum() + " " + contacts[i].getstreetname() + " " + contacts[i].gettown() + " " + contacts[i].getpostcode());
}
}

public boolean load() {
try {
    File fr = new File(fileName);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(fr);
    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
        String oStore = s.nextLine();
        String[] aStore = oStore.split(" : ");
        contacts[count]=new Contact(aStore[0], aStore[1], aStore[2], aStore[3], aStore[4]);
        count++;
    }
    s.close();
    return true;
}
catch (Exception e){
    return false;
}
}

public boolean save () {
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        fw.write(contacts[i].getname() + " " + contacts[i].gethousenum() + " " + contacts[i].getstreetname() + " " + contacts[i].gettown() + " " + contacts[i].getpostcode());
    }
    fw.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
return true;    
}

}
```

addressbookmain.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class addressbookmain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
AddressBook a1 = new AddressBook("contacts.txt");

a1.load();
System.out.println("Welcome to my address book.");
System.out.println("");

displayMenu();
}

public static void displayMenu() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("What would you like to do? Enter 1, 2, 3, etc.");
    System.out.println("1. Create a new address book");
    System.out.println("2. Add a new contact");
    System.out.println("3. Remove a contact");
    System.out.println("4. Save current address book");
    System.out.println("5. Show the current address book");
    System.out.println("6. Search for  a contact");


    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("/nWould you like to create a new address book?");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("/nPlease enter details for the new contact");
            System.out.print("Full name:");
            String name = in.next();
            System.out.print("House Number:");
            String housenum = in.next();
            System.out.print("Street Name:");
            String streetname = in.next();
            System.out.print("Town:");
            String town = in.next();
            System.out.print("Postcode:");
            String postcode = in.next();
            a1.add(new Contact(name, housenum, streetname, town, postcode));
            System.out.println("Contact has been added.");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.print("Enter a name to remove the address: ");
            Scanner rs = new Scanner(System.in);
            String deleteContact = rs.nextLine();
            a1.remove(deleteContact);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("/nAddress Book saved");
            a1.save();
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("/nHere is the current address book");
            a1.display();
            break;

        case 6:
            System.out.print("Enter a name to search for the corresponding address: ");
            Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
            String searchContact = ss.nextLine();
            a1.search(searchContact);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 6.");        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `public address getaddress() {` should be `public String getaddress() {` (or `getAddress()` to be inline with Java naming conventions); which is the other line?

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem but i would suggest following java naming conventions.. as in `Classes begin with uppercase letters`  and also `camel casing` like `getAddress()`